# How to declare global variable in html and javascript

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

How can I declare a global variable in html and javascript for a django template page. I want to make display_language to be a global variables.

```
<script>
  function onChange(){
    if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200) {
        //request is successful. So retrieve the values in the response
        display_language = xmlHttp.responseText.split(';');
        alert("response: " + display_language);
   }
}
 </script>
```

---

```
<html>
  <body>
     {% ifequal item.lang display_language %}
           {{item.text.strip}}
     {% endifequal %}
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Or `var varname = 'value';` placed outside all functions will make a global JS variable, but no client-side JS variables will be accessible from your server-side code...

Comment: @nnnnnn: and one day you refactor the code and don't notice that. And after moving something to a function - you'll have happy debugging times :)

Comment: It already is (not local in function and as result global)... unless you mean something else when you say "global"...

Comment: @zerkms - I don't refactor my code: no need when it starts out already perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables in JavaScript are implicitly global, so unless they are within a function and prefixed with the var keyword, they will be globally accessible

This is global

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    foobar = 'hello';
</script>
```

This is also global

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   function test() {
       foobar = 'hi';
   }
</script>
```

This is local

```
function test() {
    var foobar = 'world'; 
}
```

Comment: Why didn't you specify the least error-prone method with `window.foobar`?

Comment: Because I think that global variable usage should not be encourage hence I really don't think we need to learn more ways of doing that

Comment: "Because I think that global variable usage should not be encourage" -- how this justifies solutions that won't even pass `"use strict"` ? I don't even mention that it is all error prone in case if you ever move the code to the function and got happy debugging times. Right, globals are bad. But isn't proposing bad solutions for bad practice is twice as bad?